# This is what is happening when I run "flutter run"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HUTS\Documents\firebase and flutter\coffe_time\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':cloud_firestore'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        30.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[My setting.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79h3N.png)

[build gradle /android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LCq3.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Having the same issue with another package audioPlayers. Did you manage to solve it?